# Magento 2.4.1: Class Magento\Elasticsearch\Model\Adapter\FieldMapper\ProductFieldMapper does not exist

Tags: magento2.3, elasticsearch

After successful upgrade to Magento 2.4.1 logging in to Magento admin displays the error message below. What is the fix for this? Thanks.

```
1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (ReflectionException): Class Magento\Elasticsearch\Model\Adapter\FieldMapper\ProductFieldMapper does not exist

Exception #0 (ReflectionException): Class Magento\Elasticsearch\Model\Adapter\FieldMapper\ProductFieldMapper does not exist
<pre>#1 Magento\Framework\Code\Reader\ClassReader->getConstructor() called at [vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Definition/Runtime.php:54]
#2 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Definition\Runtime->getParameters() called at [vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Compiled.php:100]
#3 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Compiled->create() called at [vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php:70]
#4 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->get() called at [vendor/wyomind/framework/Helper/License.php:11]
#5 Wyomind\Framework\Helper\License->constructor() called at [vendor/wyomind/elasticsearchbrowser/Helper/Data.php:28]
#6 Wyomind\ElasticsearchBrowser\Helper\Data->__construct() called at [vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php:121]
#7 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->createObject() called at [vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Compiled.php:108]
#8 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Compiled->create() called at [vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php:70]
#9 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->get() called at [vendor/wyomind/framework/Helper/License.php:11]
#10 Wyomind\Framework\Helper\License->constructor() called at [vendor/wyomind/elasticsearchbrowser/Plugin/Ui/Config/Data.php:13]
#11 Wyomind\ElasticsearchBrowser\Plugin\Ui\Config\Data->__construct() called at [vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php:121]
#12 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->createObject() called at [vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Compiled.php:108]
#13 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Compiled->create() called at [vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php:70]
#14 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->get() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/PluginList/PluginList.php:174]
#15 Magento\Framework\Interception\PluginList\PluginList->getPlugin() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:133]
#16 Magento\Ui\Config\Data\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:153]
#17 Magento\Ui\Config\Data\Interceptor->___callPlugins() called at [generated/code/Magento/Ui/Config/Data/Interceptor.php:23]
#18 Magento\Ui\Config\Data\Interceptor->get() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/Reader/UiComponent.php:100]
#19 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Reader\UiComponent->interpret() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/ReaderPool.php:105]
#20 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\ReaderPool->interpret() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/Reader/Container.php:84]
#21 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Reader\Container->interpret() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/ReaderPool.php:105]
#22 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\ReaderPool->interpret() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Page/Config/Reader/Body.php:68]
#23 Magento\Framework\View\Page\Config\Reader\Body->interpret() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/ReaderPool.php:105]
#24 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\ReaderPool->interpret() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:334]
#25 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->generateElements() called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php:32]
#26 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->generateElements() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/Builder.php:129]
#27 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Builder->generateLayoutBlocks() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Page/Builder.php:65]
#28 Magento\Framework\View\Page\Builder->generateLayoutBlocks() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/Builder.php:65]
#29 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Builder->build() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Page/Config.php:224]
#30 Magento\Framework\View\Page\Config->build() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Page/Config.php:237]
#31 Magento\Framework\View\Page\Config->publicBuild() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Result/Page.php:242]
#32 Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page->render() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Result/Layout.php:171]
#33 Magento\Framework\View\Result\Layout->renderResult() called at [generated/code/Magento/Backend/Model/View/Result/Page/Interceptor.php:23]
#34 Magento\Backend\Model\View\Result\Page\Interceptor->renderResult() called at [vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php:120]
#35 Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch() called at [vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php:263]
#36 Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run() called at [index.php:39]
</pre>
```

Comment: Review your list of disabled modules, make sure all Elasticsearch modules are enabled. If you are using REDIS for system cache, restart or clear the redis server cache.

Comment: All Elasticsearch modules are enabled. Magento_Elasticsearch, Magento_Elasticsearch7 and Magento_Elasticsearch6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per logs, its more like module `wyomind/elasticsearchbrowser` having some plugings/virtual types on class
`Class Magento\Elasticsearch\Model\Adapter\FieldMapper\ProductFieldMapper` which was present till Magento 2.3 versions([See 2.3 version file on github](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.3/app/code/Magento/Elasticsearch/Model/Adapter/FieldMapper/ProductFieldMapper.php)).

Now since 2.4 versions class is not available in 2.4 Magento(try to switch to 2.4 branch and check, you will get 404).

You should give a try to upgrade wyomind module compatible to Magento 2.4 versions.

Ref. - https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/21916

Comment: Are you suggesting I upgrade wyomind/elasticsearchbrowser to fix the issue?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. This helped fix the issue. Great job

Comment: Great..glad to help you